# Valid JSON gives error while parsing - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token S

Tags: json, parsing

I have a valid JSON string as below:- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/shubh0602/sNRNc/)

```
[
   {
      "field":"Name",
      "rules":[
         {
            "Regex":"\\S",
            "ValidationMessage":" Name cannot be blank."
         },
         {
            "Regex":"^.{1,50}$",
            "ValidationMessage":"Length should not exceeds 50 characters."
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "field":"Abbreviation",
      "rules":[
         {
            "Regex":"\\S",
            "ValidationMessage":" Abbreviation cannot be blank."
         },
         {
            "Regex":"^.{1,15}$",
            "ValidationMessage":"Length should not exceeds 15 characters."
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "field":"PhoneNumber",
      "rules":[
         {
            "Regex":"\\S",
            "ValidationMessage":"Phone Number cannot be blank."
         },
         {
            "Regex":"^\\d{10}$",
            "ValidationMessage":"Length must be 10 digits"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "field":"SelectedCampus",
      "rules":[
         {
            "Regex":"\\S",
            "ValidationMessage":"Please st Serviced Campus"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

When I do JSON.parse it is throwing error as :-

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token S
```

Comment: Have u validate Json in using any online validator?

Comment: @AntoKing Yes, thats why i said its Valid JSON. I have used http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Just now did with http://jsonlint.com/ also

Comment: @Degnome: You'll need to double-escape it. Like: `\\\\S`. Do a `console.log(validations)`, you'll understand. :)

Comment: Let me try Thrustmaster

Comment: Now I am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token d ` after changing `\\S` to `\\\\S` ... [Fiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/shubh0602/sNRNc/7/)

Comment: @Degnome: Yes, that's because you also have: `^\\d{10}$` .. Change all of them.

Comment: Dude you Rock... You may post it as answer.... It will be heartily accepted :) I missed `^\\d{10}$` ... In the mean while I'll google around to check why I need to double escape it...

Comment: Nice that you got answer and also n any time u can easy parse your json using online http://json.parser.online.fr/ if you have any problem in future

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer: you will need to double escape your JSON string, before you can parse it with `JSON.parse(..)`.

Let's take a string like, say, `\\S`. It consists of two characters: `'\\', 'S'`.

`JSON.parse("...\\S...")` sees that as a back-slash, and expects one of 'n', 'r', 't' (or other escape characters) after it. It neither expects `S` or a `d`. Hence you get that error.

To solve, you will need to double escape the JSON String. Like: `\\\\S` & `\\\\d`.